# How to programmatically upload image to the wordpress and set it as featured image?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here, In this **functions.php** file what i am trying to do is I am fetching the image from my post content actually i am using the image_url in content ( This part of fetching the first image is working fine , I have tested it ) . The problem is that i can't upload the image using the url and set it as a featured_image getting the ' published failed ' popup. Anyone can you help me out , or if you have another way ?

```
function generate_post_featured_image($post_ID) {
$post = get_post($post_ID);

if (empty($post->featured_image)) {
    // Find the first image URL in the post content
    preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1])) {
        $image_url = $matches[1];

        // Sideload the image and get the attachment ID
        $attachment_id = media_sideload_image($image_url, $post_ID, null, 'id');

        if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id) && !empty($attachment_id)) {
            // Set the attachment ID as the featured image
            set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, $attachment_id);
        } else {
            $error_message = $attachment_id->get_error_message();
            echo 'Error sideloading image: ' . $error_message;
        }
    }
}
}

add_action('publish_post', 'generate_post_featured_image');
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the uploading that is failing or the making it the featured image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function upload_image_and_set_featured($post_ID) {
    $post = get_post($post_ID);

    if (empty($post->featured_image)) {
        // Find the first image URL in the post content
        preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
        if (isset($matches[1])) {
            $image_url = $matches[1];

            // Upload the image and get the attachment ID
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
            $filename = basename($image_url);
            if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
            } else {
                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
            }
            file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $post_ID);
            if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file);
                wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
                set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, $attachment_id);
            } else {
                $error_message = $attachment_id->get_error_message();
                echo 'Error uploading image: ' . $error_message;
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('publish_post', 'upload_image_and_set_featured');
```

Add the above code in your **function.php**. this code takes the first image from your content and set it in the featured image.

Comment: It would be useful if you could explain what the code does that differs from the code in the question and why it is necessary.

Comment: I don't want to upload any featured image , I just want that whenever i publish my post then it should automatically select the first image from my content field . In my content field the image that i am using are from external website .

Comment: By the thanks for reply but I already got the solution actually I got  a plugin which does the same thing.